# In photoshop, is there a way to inverse the effect of brush pressure opacity?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

If this is possible, then I could have a brush stroke, with brush pressure size turned on, that starts out small and at full opacity and then becomes larger with less opacity as pressure is increased.

Comment: I am not sure how you would have this done automatically while using the brush but You can apply a layer mask for that brush stroke layer and do an opacity gradient for that stroke layer

Comment: That seems like it would take a lot of time, but maybe I'm not understanding correctly. Are brush stroke layers the same as the layers in the 'Layers' panel?

Comment: Yea, I just don't think there is an option to inverse the pen pressure like you want to do. Yes they are the same, I was referring to the layer as a brush stroke that is on a layer, not anything different than a regular Photoshop layer.

Comment: I would agree, it's not possible to reverse the pressure input (not even at the OS level). A layer with a mask is about the only way.. or paint, then flip the layer. Start out pushing harder and lighted up as you paint... or start light and push harder as you paint. :)